# Magento Redis CPU usage High redis-rdb-bgsave

Tags: magento, redis

Out of the blue my Magento 2.3 installatie crashed, the CPU suddely raises and eventually Magento crashes. No updates or something like that, so that can't be te cause.

Main cause seems to be Redis, after stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no in Redis the system didn't crash anymore, but memory and CPU usage are stil high.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause, google was doing something like a DDOS attack. 150k requests per day...

Adjusted the robots.txt to do less indexing

[image]